# Can I sort ArrayList of ArrayList simply by using TreeSet?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashset, treeset

=== MAJOR EDIT (and a minor one) ===

I've completely rewritten the code I submitted a couple of days ago since it was based on two others' not-so-well-thought-out hunks of code, a very inappropriate idea from the gitgo. My bad for failing to research enough.

Nevertheless, @F. Böller was kind enough to Answer the question about my original code and said I needed to define a `comparator` in this context:
`TreeSet<ArrayList<Integer>> hs = new TreeSet<>(comparator);`.

That was all the encouragement I needed to Google [java treesort comparator](http://www.java2novice.com/java-collections-and-util/treeset/comparator-object/) and based my revision on what I saw there. It wasn't at all easy and I confess I still don't quite know WHY the syntax below turned out to largely be all I needed, but I'd've never come up with it without the example at the Googled link above.

`TreeSet<Leaf> theTreeSet = new TreeSet<>(new HowToCompareLeaves());`

=== minor EDIT-- THE FOLLOWING LINE IS WRONG:

Anyway, the code below works great (sorts based on 1st element in each "leaf").

=== THE FOLLOWING LINE IS CORRECT:

Anyway, the code below works great (sorts and compares ALL elements in each "leaf").

=== end minor edit ===

However, I'd appreciate it if someone could **explain (to someone who'd never used `TreeSet` before) what the line above actually does. It seems to define a new instance of what's defined as the method for comparing the data items that `ar` is composed of... Is that it?? Is it a constructor for the new `TreeSet` that is required to define how it sorts new elements into itself??**

```
package treed;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class TreeSetExample {

  public static final int NR = 4, NC = 3;

  public static void main(String a[])
  {
    ArrayList<Leaf> ar = new ArrayList<>(NR);

    for (int i = 0; i < NR; i++)
     ar.add(new Leaf());

    System.out.println("Pre-sort:");
    for(int i = 0; i < NR; i++)
      System.out.println(ar.get(i));

    TreeSet<Leaf> theTreeSet = new TreeSet<>(new HowToCompareLeaves());

    System.out.println("\nPost-sort:");
    for (int i = 0; i < NR; i++)
      theTreeSet.add(ar.get(i));

    for(Leaf e:theTreeSet)           
      System.out.println(e);
  }
}

class HowToCompareLeaves implements Comparator<Leaf>
{
  @Override 
  public int compare(Leaf e, Leaf f) 
  {
    if(e.row.get(0) > f.row.get(0)) return  1;
    if(e.row.get(0) < f.row.get(0)) return -1;
    return 0;
  }
}    

class Leaf
{
    ArrayList<Integer> row;  

    Leaf()
    {
      row = new ArrayList<>(TreeSetExample.NC);
      for (int i = 0; i < TreeSetExample.NC; i++)
        row.add((int)(Math.random()*89 + 10));
    }

  public String toString()
  {
    String s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < TreeSetExample.NC; i++) {
      s += row.get(i) + "...";
    }
    return s;
  }
}
```

=== end of EDIT; rest is trash =======================

I was following a new unanswered question about an ArrayList of ArrayList that needed un-dupe-ing and sorting. One answer suggested using a `HashSet` to enable removing duplicates, but that doesn't sort, as the working code below confirms.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class TwoDimArrayList {

  static           ArrayList<Integer> r;
  static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> a2D = new ArrayList<>();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      r = new ArrayList<>();
      for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        r.add((int)(Math.random() * 89 + 11));
      a2D.add(r);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < a2D.size(); i++){
      for (int j = 0; j < a2D.get(i).size(); j++) 
        System.out.print(a2D.get(i).get(j) + "\t");
      System.out.println("...");
    }

    HashSet<ArrayList<Integer>> hs = new HashSet<>(a2D.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < a2D.size(); i++)
      hs.add(a2D.get(i));

    a2D.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < hs.size(); i++)
      a2D.add((ArrayList<Integer>) hs.toArray()[i]);

    for (int i = 0; i < a2D.size(); i++){ 
      for (int j = 0; j < a2D.get(i).size(); j++)
        System.out.print(a2D.get(i).get(j) + "\t");
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

I tried simply changing `HashSet` to `TreeSet` since the latter provides sorting:

```
TreeSet<ArrayList<Integer>> hs = new TreeSet<>(a2D.size());
```

That gave error: `cannot infer arguments for TreeSet`. So I eventually got rid of it like so:

```
TreeSet<ArrayList<Integer>> hs = new TreeSet<>();
```

But I get error on this line:

```
  hs.add(a2D.get(i));
```

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable`

Is there some easy fix to this? Or is hoping that `TreeSet` will do the sorting in and of itself just wrong? (I'm new to sets, in case anyone was wondering...)

Comment: **How** did you expect such list to be sorted?  In order to sort you need at the very least to be able to **compare** its elements.

Comment: More specifically, by what criterion do you want your list of lists to be sorted?

Comment: I guess implementing `Comparable` is where to go next. Like I said, new to Sets and never before used either `HashSet` or `TreeSet`. And I guess I assumed there'd be a default sort order. I should have done some more research before posting. Also, I assumed that the other thread's poster, who used a short loop with a `HashSet`, had something concrete from which to proceed, since the code that I evolved from it does eliminate dupes. So I'm off to research. Thanks for waking me gently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The TreeSet doesn't know, how to sort the ArrayLists, because there is no natural ordering for Lists. Should it compare Lists by the min of the values, the average value of list or something else?
To make the TreeSet understand on what you want to sort, you have to add an comparator to the constructor:

```
TreeSet<ArrayList<Integer>> hs = new TreeSet<>(comparator);
```

The comparator has to realize the Interface `Comparator<ArrayList>`. Here you can define, how to order the ArrayList.
If you don't add an comparator, the TreeSet implicitly expects the ArrayList to realize the Comparable-Interface, which it does not do.

Comment: --Thanks for the suggestion instead of just brushing me aside with a (much-deserved) downvote. I finally got the job done thanks to your one line.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort a list of `List<Integer>`, than you will have to write the logic for this yourselves. Java can't automatically deduce this ordering.

The `TreeSet` uses the natural order of your element to keep the entire Set sorted. In your case however this natural ordering is undefined, hence the `ClassCastException`.